# oozie spark 2.0 action giving exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I am getting the below exception while trying to run a spark action using oozie

```
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.builder(SparkSession.scala:861)
    at com.spark.morbiditymerge.MorbidityProcessMessage$.main(MorbidityProcessMessage.scala:19)
    at com.spark.morbiditymerge.MorbidityProcessMessage.main(MorbidityProcessMessage.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

The spark code is running fine locally in eclipse. But, I am getting the above exception while trying to run it using oozie.

I am using spark 2.0 and scala 2.11.8. I have included all the spark 2.0 dependencies in my pom file.

I read in the cloudera documentation that Oozie Spark2 Action is not Supported. Is that the reason why I am getting this exception? If yes, is there any other way to run a spark 2.0 job using oozie?

Comment: you are using the uber jar or thin jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this issue and was able to find a workaround. Create an Oozie **Shell** action that calls `spark2-submit` with your necessary parameters.

Otherwise If you would rather use the spark action on CDH, you might consider rewriting your code in 1.6.

Comment: I tried creating a oozie shell action to call spark submit like this --> spark-submit --class com.spark.morbiditymerge.MorbidityProcessMessage --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue eda1_e360 --executor-memory 20G --num-executors 50 hdfs://cdhdev/user/yxs7634/morbiditymerge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. But, I got the below exception org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yxs7634, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/yarn/.sparkStaging/application_1505336691782_403270":yarn:supergroup:drwx------

Comment: You are trying to execute code as a user but the application directory is owned by the super group. I'm afraid I can't help much with that but you may try talking to your ops team. Are you able to execute a simple bash command (such as `sleep 10` as a shell action?)

Answer (score 1):

you have the option to setup the oozie share lib for spark2 and then use this spark2 oozie library by setting `oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2` either in `job.properties` or in `workflow.xml` spark action as

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark</name>
    <value>spark2</value>
</property>
```

For setting up the oozie share lib for spark2, follow the [hortonworks documnet section Configuring Oozie Spark Action for Spark 2](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html). The same steps can be followed in CDH, but the paths specified needs modification as per the CDH cluster settings. I am successfully executing the spark2 jobs using oozie spark action in cdh.

Answer (score 0):

as per CDH community document oozie not compatibility with spark2.0.
so you should use oozie with spark1.6

below is the link for CDH reference - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#ki_oozie_spark_action

happy learning:)